# SQL SERVER select month with maximum loans taken

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a db table with the following structure:

```
CREATE table credite(
nr_contract char(30),
data_incheierii date,

rata_dobinzii int,
valoare_credit float,

nr_rate int,
cod_client char(30),

PRIMARY key (nr_contract),
FOREIGN KEY(cod_client) REFERENCES clienti(cod_client)
);
```

some sample data:

```
insert into credite
Values ('xsdfghu77','2007-04-02',7.8,20000,12,'43e3rtysr');

insert into credite
Values ('xdfgui767','1980-04-11',7.8,100000,12,'43e3rtyhu');

insert into credite
Values ('xcvbhyty7','1999-10-01',7.8,300000,24,'43e3rtyhv');

insert into credite
Values ('xzasdrtgh','2000-04-02',5.0,10000,6,'43e3rtysr');

insert into credite
Values ('xsdfghu77','2007-04-02',7.8,20000,12,'43e3rtysr');
```

I need to find the date when there were formed the maximum number of loans.
**(data_incheierii which is included in sample data the most times)**

I tried so:

```
SELECT 
MAX(d.incheierii) FROM(Select COUNT(data_incheierii) as incheierii from credite) as d
```

but i cannot return the data_incheierii as I get syntactic error. How to write the query correctly?

Comment: Add sample data pls

Comment: You've tagged MySQL and SQL Server. Which is it? Please update your tags.

Comment: I will udate now the question, but my db is in another language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can do:

```
select date_created_loan, count(*) as cnt
from credite
group by date_created_loan
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note:  `fetch first 1 row only` is the ANSI-standard syntax for getting the first row.  Some databases use `limit`; some use `select top (1)`; some use other constructs as well.

In SQL Server, you can also do:

```
select top (1) date_created_loan, count(*) as cnt
from credite
group by date_created_loan
order by count(*) desc;
```

You can use `top (1) with ties` if you want all top dates.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this sql query.

```
 SELECT top 1 CAST(MONTH(datecolumn) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(datecolumn) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS MonthYear, 
    count(*) AS mycount
    FROM mytablename
    GROUP BY CAST(MONTH(datecolumn) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(datecolumn) AS VARCHAR(4))
    ORDER BY mycount desc
```

Comment: Did you read the part of the question where he said he wanted the month?